# jQuery click event does not work

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have problem in my `.js` code

the code :

```
<script language="javascript">
$('#firstButton').click(function(){
    $.getJSON("traitementReady.php",function(data){
        $("#categories").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            $("#categories").append(" <button id="+this['Id']+"  class='categorie'>"+this['Libelle']+"</button>");
        });
    });
});

$('.categorie').click(function(){
    alert("Yes");
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<button id="firstButton" name="buttton">OK</button>
<div id="categories"></div>
```

If I click button (OK), I have the all value (button class(categorie)) in `div (id=categories)`, but if I click one button  among button loaded with the click    button (OK), I get nothing(no alert("yes")).

Comment: there can be a problem with the code inside the click handler. try put some break points and debug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way;

```
$(document).on('click','.categorie',function(){

alert("Yes");

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

put click code inside firstbutton click so as to attach handler immediately after creation

```
$('#firstButton').bind('click',function(){
    ...
    $("#categories").empty();
    ...
    $('.categorie').off('click');//remove previous so as to avoid multiple bindings
   $('.categorie').on('click',function(e,o){
    alert("Yes");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some slight differences in "on","bind" and "live", if your HTML is dynamically creating then you can use

jquery("xxx").live('click',function(){XXXXX});

Bind will actually force the click to trigger but html should already there.

Hope this will help.

Cheers!!